# Test with JUnit an request

Tags: junit, kotlin, rx-java

I wanna to test an request with JUnit with an request like this but RxUtils.applySchedulersAndErrorMapper() return null. Is any possibilities to test that?

```
override fun onContinueClicked(phoneNumber: String) {
    mView.showLoading()
    mUserService.checkUserApprovedStatus(phoneNumber)
                .compose(RxUtils.applySchedulersAndErrorMapper())
                .subscribe({ response ->
                    //Success
                }, { error ->
                    //Error
                })
}
```

here is where I setup the presenter and mUserService for presenter

```
@Mock
private PhoneContract.View view;

@Mock
private UserService userService;

  @Before
public void setup() {
    presenter = new PhonePresenter(this.view);
    presenter.mUserService = userService;
}
```

here is the test method

```
 @Test
public void onContinueClicked_SendJustNumbers() {
    String phoneNumber = "(01234567890)";
    // when
    presenter.onContinueClicked(phoneNumber);
    // then
    verify(view, times(1)).showLoading();
}
```

and here is the RXUtils class:

```
class RxUtils {
    companion object {

        @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
        fun <E> applySchedulersAndErrorMapper(): ObservableTransformer<E, E> {
            return ObservableTransformer { o ->
                o.flatMap(Function<E, ObservableSource<E>> { element ->
                    val genericResponse = element as GenericResponse<*>
                    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                    return@Function Observable.just(genericResponse as E)
                }).onErrorResumeNext(Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<E>> { t ->
                    if (t is ApiException) {
                        return@Function Observable.error(t)
                    }
                    var genericResponse: GenericResponse<*>? = null

                    return@Function Observable.error(ApiException(t.message ?: "", genericResponse?.result ?: Result()))
                })
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the stacktrace where I receive null for RxUtils.applySchedulersAndErrorMapper()

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it relates to the SDK, it probably won't work in a unit test. You didn't include your imports, so it's impossible to tell at a glance, but I know from experience that you can't use this in a unit test

```
AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
```

You need to replace that with, say, Schedulers.trampoline()

**Example of how to set a custom scheduler for testing**

Note, this is only an example, and there are other valid solutions.

```
class RxUtils {
companion object {

    // add this
    @VisibleForTesting var mainScheduler = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
    @VisibleForTesting var ioScheduler = Schedulers.io()

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    fun <E> applySchedulersAndErrorMapper(): ObservableTransformer<E, E> {
        return ObservableTransformer { o ->
            o.flatMap(Function<E, ObservableSource<E>> { element ->
                val genericResponse = element as GenericResponse<*>
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return@Function Observable.just(genericResponse as E)
            }).onErrorResumeNext(Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<E>> { t ->
                if (t is ApiException) {
                    return@Function Observable.error(t)
                }
                var genericResponse: GenericResponse<*>? = null

                return@Function Observable.error(ApiException(t.message ?: "", genericResponse?.result ?: Result()))
            })
                    .observeOn(mainScheduler)
                    .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
        }
    }
}
```

}

**And in your test:**

```
@Before fun setup() {
    RxUtils.mainScheduler = Schedulers.trampoline()
    RxUtils.ioScheduler = Schedulers.trampoline()
}

@After fun teardown() {
    RxUtils.mainScheduler = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
    RxUtils.ioScheduler = Schedulers.io()
}
```

**EDIT in response to updated post with more information on test**

First of all, you should post WAY MORE CODE. It's frustrating having to pull it out of you by dribs and drabs. Anyway. You have the following:

```
@Mock
private UserService userService;
```

That creates a mock `UserService`, sure, but it doesn't *stub* anything. When you call `userService.anyFunctionAtAll()`, it will return null by default. There's your NPE. You have to stub it. For example:

```
Mockito.when(userService.anyFunctionAtAll()).thenReturn(somePredeterminedValue)
```

Please refer to the Mockito [website](http://site.mockito.org/) for more information.

Comment: it`s posible to mock RxUtils?

Comment: Mocking static methods is not easy nor recommended. Instead, use some indirection that lets you specify different schedulers in a test environment.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: still NullPointerException for ".compose(RxUtils.applySchedulers())"

Comment: You still haven't included your test code. What are you using PowerMock for?

Comment: I added the test code. Yes, I use PowerMock for testing.

Comment: What does `presenter.onContinueClicked(phoneNumber)` do? Do you have `mUserService.checkUserApprovedStatus(phoneNumber)` stubbed? What are you mocking with PowerMock?